# jQuery fadeOut() and fadein() timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-effects

I've a simple problem with jQuery, checkout this: http://jsfiddle.net/4Q5uQ/

How to fadeIn() the box after the fadeOut() effect is completed?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean a bit? Right now the fadeout happens first then a fadein happens. Do you want to reverse this?

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie no. If you run that code and you click on the "Link 2" you can see the two effect is in overlay. I would to run the fadeOut() and when is totally completed, trigger fadeIn() on the `$(".box[data=" + data + "]")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want two things:

1. The fading `<div>`s should be in the same place so they don't move around.
2. You want to fade out the visible `<div>` and then fade in the other `<div>`.

The first can be done by wrapping the two `<div>`s in a relatively positioned `<div>` and then absolutely positioning the inner `<div>`s:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="div_1" data="1" class="box">
        test_1
    </div>
    <div id="div_2" data="2" class="box">
        test_2
    </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
div.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
div.box {
    /* ... */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

The second is just a matter of adding [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) to your `fadeOut` selector:

```
$(".box:visible").fadeOut(1000, ...
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/jAP2b/

Comment: Only an information: why should we fix the div with the `position` css property? I mean why the second div isn't in the same place of the first div if I hide the first one.

Comment: @Fred: Strictly speaking you don't need the absolute positioning with your current animation, adding `:visible` gets the right `<div>` out of the way before the next one comes in. However, with the positioning, you could fade-out and fade-in at the same time without changing the HTML or CSS. You don't need it but it doesn't hurt and gives you a bit more flexibility on how you want to animate things.

Answer (score 1):

Following code may be your need: http://jsfiddle.net/4Q5uQ/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        var fin = $(this).attr('fin');
        var fout = $(this).attr('fout');
        $("#div_" + fout).show();
        $("#div_" + fin).hide();
        $(".box[data=" + fout + "]").fadeOut(4000, function() {
            $(".box[data=" + fin + "]").fadeIn(4000);
        });
    });
});
```